# Combinar valores de dos columnas para hacerlos únicos

Tags: mysql

Al intentar registrar datos de forma aleatoria en una tabla me gustaría que hubiera la restricción de que dos valores combinados de dos columnas diferentes no se pudieran repetir. No me estoy refiriendo a datos únicos de forma individual, sino que esos dos datos en esas dos columnas al mismo tiempo no se puedan producir más de una vez.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Muestra tu consulta y qué has intentado. Asegúrate de que el código esté como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Debes agregar una restriccion 'UNIQUE' a ambas columnas

Comment: Exactamente, al final encontré la solución, no sabía como hacerlos para ambas columnas. Gracias igualmente.

`ALTER TABLE `grades` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`grades_students_id`, `grades_courses_id`);`